# SHFileOperation creates empty directory instead of file

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to copy a file from one location to another using SHFileOperation:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop;
fileop.hwnd = 0;
fileop.wFunc = FO_COPY;
fileop.pFrom = L"C:\\SomeDirectory\\SomeName.jpg\0";
fileop.pTo = L"C:\\SomeOtherDirectory\\SomeName.jpg\0";
fileop.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT;
fileop.fAnyOperationsAborted = FALSE;
fileop.hNameMappings = 0;
fileop.lpszProgressTitle = 0;
SHFileOperation(&fileop);
```

The problem is that instead of getting a copy of SomeName.jpg in SomeOtherDirectory an empty directory with name SomeOtherDirectory\SomeName.jpg is created, any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `FO_COPY` and `FO_MOVE` operations the `pTo` member of the `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` must be a location, i.e. a directory, and not a destination filename. The directory is allowed not to exist, in which case it is created even if it looks like a filename.

You should either just specify `"C:\\SomeOtherDiretory\0"` or use `FO_RENAME`.

As to why your file is not created, have you checked the return value?

Comment: But MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28VS.85%29.aspx) says `pTo` is *A pointer to the destination file or directory name*.

Comment: @Naveen: you have to read the documentation for `wFunc` as well to see how it is used.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. If a folder is specified as destination, nothing happens for such files, they are either turned into folders or ignored by SHFileOperation. The bug only happens for some files. I work around it like this:
`if(!CopyFile(...)) SHFileOperation(...);`